# "connection.Children(0)" triggers "The enumerator of the collection cannot find en element with the specified index."

Tags: vbscript, sap-gui

I am using a VBScript to login automatically into SAP GUI.
It opens automatically the SAP GUI window, it loads the SAP server, but it doesn't populate automatically the user and password fields (remain blank).

It also gives a script error on line 52, char 4:

> The enumerator of the collection cannot find en element with the specified index.

The code is the following:

```
REM The following script was written to log into the SAP server automatically.
REM To view historical information and credit for this script please see
REM the following thread on the SAP Community Network:
REM http://scn.sap.com/thread/3763970

REM This script was last updated by Paul Street on 7/1/15

REM Directives
    Option Explicit

  REM Variables!  Must declare before using because of Option Explicit
    Dim WSHShell, SAPGUIPath, SID, InstanceNo, WinTitle, SapGuiAuto, application, connection, session

  REM Main
    Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    If IsObject(WSHShell) Then

      REM Set the path to the SAP GUI directory
        SAPGUIPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\"

      REM Set the SAP system ID
        SID = "eaiserver.domain.com"

      REM Set the instance number of the SAP system
        InstanceNo = "38"

      REM Starts the SAP GUI
        WSHShell.Exec SAPGUIPath & "SAPgui.exe " & SID & " " & _
          InstanceNo
 
      REM Set the title of the SAP GUI window here
        WinTitle = "SAP"
 
      While Not WSHShell.AppActivate(WinTitle)
        WScript.Sleep 250
      Wend
 
      Set WSHShell = Nothing
    End If
 
    REM Remove this if you need to test the above script and want a message box at the end launching the login screen.
    REM MsgBox "Here now your script..." 
     
    If Not IsObject(application) Then
       Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
       Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    End If
    If Not IsObject(connection) Then
       Set connection = application.Children(0)
    End If
    If Not IsObject(session) Then
       Set session    = connection.Children(0)
    End If
    If IsObject(WScript) Then
       WScript.ConnectObject session,     "on"
       WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
    End If
    session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-MANDT").Text = "100"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").text = "I'veInsertedtheCorrectUsernameHere"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").text = "I'veInsertedtheCorrectPassHere"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-LANGU").Text = "PT"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").setFocus
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").caretPosition = 10
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I am using the exact same script, which I found somewhere on the SAP help forums.

When I've encountered this issue before it's usually because the SAP GUI window was loaded AFTER lines

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").text = "username"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").text = "password"
```

There are two ways to fix this particular script.  One is to add a `MsgBox` that will pause the script, but give SAP GUI enough time to load.  The other is to add `WScript.Sleep(<a few seconds>)` to allow SAP GUI to load.  Like so ...

*Note that the below code has BOTH examples, but only 1 is necessary.  I prefer the `.Sleep()` because it requires no external input from a user.*

```
If IsObject(WSHShell) Then
    ' Removed for clarity
End If

MsgBox "Click OK to continue" ' <-- MsgBox to pause script
WScript.Sleep(5000) ' <--- Wait 5 seconds for SAP GUI to load

If Not IsObject(application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session    = connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session,     "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]").resizeWorkingPane 164,40,false
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").text = "username"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").text = "password"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").caretPosition = 14
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
```

And of course, storing username and password in plain text is not a good practice.  However, obfuscating passwords with the VBScript `InputBox()` is not possible.  You will have to use the command line, or create an IE object which is outside the scope of this question

Answer (score 1):

Here's some VBS code that tries to wait for SAP to login and load properly. It worked well for me so far.

```
Function SAP_start_and_login(connection_string, use_sso, user, pass)
    WScript.Echo "executing function SAP_start_and_login()"
    REM Variables!  Must declare before using because of Option Explicit
    Dim WSHShell, SAPGUIPath
    REM Main
    Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    If IsObject(WSHShell) Then
        REM Set the path to the SAP GUI directory
        SAPGUIPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\"

        REM Starts the SAP GUI
        if use_sso then
            WSHShell.Exec SAPGUIPath & "sapshcut.exe -client={your_client} -sysname=whatevah -gui=" & connection_string & " -snc_name={your_snc_name} -snc_qop={your_snc_qop}"
        else
            WSHShell.Exec SAPGUIPath & "sapshcut.exe -client={your_client} -sysname=whatevah -gui=" & connection_string & " -user=" & user & " -pw=" & pass
        end if
        REM WSHShell.Exec SAPGUIPath & "saplogon.exe """ & system & """"
        Set WSHShell = Nothing
        WScript.Echo "{waiting for SAP to finish loading..}"
        SAP_start_and_login = WaitForSAP(connection_string, 50)
        WScript.Sleep 1000  
    End If
End Function

Function CheckSapIsRunning(connection_string)
    Running = False
    Ready = False

    If Not IsObject(application) Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
        If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
            WScript.Echo "SAPGUI object not found yet"
            ' Error raised, object not found.
            ' Restore normal error handling.
            On Error GoTo 0
        Else
            'WScript.Echo "einai ok"
            ' Object found.
            ' Restore normal error handling.
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
            If application.Connections.Count() > 0 Then
                For i = 0 To (application.Connections.Count()-1)
                    REM WScript.Echo i
                    Set Connection = application.Children(0+i)
                    Conn = Connection.ConnectionString()
                    REM WScript.Echo Conn
                    If InStr(Conn, connection_string) Then
                        Running = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            End If
            If Running Then
                REM WScript.Echo connection_string + " is running!"
                REM WScript.Echo "sessions="+CStr(connection.Children.Count)
                If Not IsObject(session) Then
                    if connection.Children.Count > 0 then
                        Set session = connection.Children(0)
                        If IsObject(WScript) Then
                            WScript.ConnectObject session,     "on"
                            WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
                        End If
                        If not session.Busy then
                            Ready=True
                            REM WScript.Echo connection_string + " session is ready!"
                            Dim sapWindow
                            set sapWindow = session.findById("wnd[0]", False)
                            if sapWindow is Nothing then
                                WScript.Echo connection_string + " sap window element not there yet"
                            else
                                WScript.Echo connection_string + " is loaded and visible!"
                            end if
                        Else
                            WScript.Echo connection_string + " session is busy!"
                        end if
                    else
                        WScript.Echo connection_string + " session not loaded yet!"
                    end if
                End If
            else
                WScript.Echo connection_string + " not running!"
            End If
        End If
    End If
    REM WScript.Echo application.Connections.Count()
    CheckSapIsRunning = Ready
End Function

Function WaitForSAP(connection_string, timeout)
    counter = 0
    returnValue = False
    While NOT CheckSapIsRunning(connection_string) AND counter < timeout
        counter = counter + 1
        WScript.Sleep 1000
        REM WScript.Echo connection_string + " is not ready"
    WEnd
    if counter = timeout then
        WScript.Echo "timeout of " + CStr(timeout) + " seconds reached."
    else
        returnValue = True
    end if
    WaitForSAP = returnValue
End Function
```

This can be used like this

```
If SAP_start_and_login(connection_string, use_sso, username, password) Then
    If Not IsObject(application) Then
        Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
        Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    End If
    ...{the rest of your recorded script}
Else
    WScript.Echo "Could not get a functioning SAP session"
    WScript.Quit 1
End If
```

I'm using sapshcut.exe because it was easy to have both SSO and non SSO in a similar manner. The connection string is important in order to distinguish and identify the instance of SAP that you want to use in the rest of the script. It can be found from your current shortcut along with the SSO parameters that you might be using. If the SSO is true the user and pass parameters are not used. The timeout is also useful to avoid an endless loop if SAP is down or unreachable.
This solution does not need a static sleep in the script in order to wait for SAP to load which could prevent issues if SAP took more than expected to load. Also no time is wasted if it is loaded sooner than expected.

Comment: Can you pls explain in a bit more detail on how to get started with this? I have a sapshortcut already on my desktop. So, how does this VBS script kick in?